# jQuery text not toggling on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle text of a span whenever it's parent anchor tag is clicked. Here is the HTML:

```
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse1">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">expand</span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

while this is the javascript of the `changeText` function which is called on each click of the anchor tag

```
function changeText() {
var taskDivClass = $('.panel-title a');
$(taskDivClass).each(
    function() {
        var $this =  $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
            taskDivSpanText.html('expand');
        }
        else {
            var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
            taskDivSpanText.html('collapse');
        }
    }
);
}
```

I'm using the `each` method because there are multiple such blocks in the page, and for each click event only that particular span should change.

The `.collapsed` class dynamically toggles on the anchor tag when user clicks on it.

The issue is when the first time user clicks on the anchor tag, the text is not toggled. On next click it does.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing here. If someone has a clue, please point it out.

Comment: You're not calling that function. add `changeText();` after

Comment: Note that jQuery UI has event handlers and hooks for this, if that's what you're using ?

Comment: I'm using this to bind the function to the click event: `$(".panel-heading").click(changeText);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to add/remove class work with .html().

Hope this will help you..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    var spanClick= $(this).find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
    if (spanClick.html()==="Expand"){
     spanClick.html("Collapse");
    }
    else{
     spanClick.html("Expand");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="panel-title">
  <a href="#collapse1"   >
    <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">Expand</span>
  </a>
</h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7vx1ueo1/2/

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to loop - the original selector already applies to all the matching elements

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-title a').on('click', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('collapse')) {
      var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
      $this.removeClass('collapse');
      taskDivSpanText.html('expand');

    } else {
      var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
      taskDivSpanText.html('collapse');
      $this.addClass('collapse');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse1" class="collapse">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">collapse</span>
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse2">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">expand</span>
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse3">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">expand</span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

**You could also** encapsulate the function into a named function like in your code

```js
$(function() {
  // define function
  var changeText = function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('collapse')) {
      var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
      $this.removeClass('collapse');
      taskDivSpanText.html('expand');

    } else {
      var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
      taskDivSpanText.html('collapse');
      $this.addClass('collapse');
    }
  };

  // bind function to click event 
  $('.panel-title a').on('click', changeText );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse1" class="collapse">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">collapse</span>
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse2">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">expand</span>
    </a>
</h2>
<h2 class="panel-title">
    <a href="#collapse3">
        <span class="ui-hidden-accessible">expand</span>
    </a>
</h2>
```

Comment: I don't want to add/remove collapse class here, so I've used this code instead:
    `$('.panel-title a').on('click', function() {

 var $this = $(this);

 if ($this.hasClass('collapse')) {
   var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
   console.log(taskDivClass);
   
   taskDivSpanText.html('expand');

 } else {
   var taskDivSpanText = $this.find('.ui-hidden-accessible');
   taskDivSpanText.html('collapse');
   
   console.log(taskDivSpanText);
 }
});`

Comment: But Console is showing error, it is showing the value `taskDivSpanText` of null

Comment: Well, `taskDivClass` was not defined in my code - why would you want to log/use it? you don't need it - you are logging `taskDivClass` but you say that `taskDivSpanText` is null (they are different elements)

Comment: @anwartheravian if you do not want to add/remove classes then you will get the same results every time since no element has the class `collapse` applied to them (as far as the HTML you provided is concerned anyway)